# Note Taking app with Full Text Search, tree structure of 20,000 notes with approx 150 KB of text

Tags: gratis, note-taking

I have tried the following tree structure note taking where the performance is very slow when I add 20,000 notes with approx 150 KB of text in each node:

1. Zim wiki
2. Cherry tree
3. Tomboy
4. Wikipad
5. Simple note

Also, looking for the following features which the above options don't have:

1. Type-ahead search like google
2. Auto-suggestion like google
3. Number of hits found on typing like folio views
4. Preview of the typed text inside the notes
5. Highlight all the occurrences of the text in the notes or text
6. Open source or freeware
7. It should be platform independent else portable

Can someone let me know which has all the above features?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be platform independent else portable.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Please edit your question to add this info, thanks :-)